# chainning with forkJoin Angular 6

Tags: observable, angular6

The form is either in add or edit mode.

action 1: 
In add mode i don't need to to pull the project data, where as in edit mode, i need to pull project data. This is conditional step.

action 2: both in add/edit mode
I have a drop down for which i need to pull the options from the DB.

I have following forkJoin

```
forkJoin(

  this.groupService.getGroupListById(zGroupTypes.ProjectSubType).pipe(
    map(res => res),
    catchError(e => throwError(e)) //of(this.errorMessageService.getErrorMessage(e))
  ),

  this.formMode === zFormMode.Add ? of(this.subProjectInfo = <SubProject>{}) : this.projectSubService.getSubProjectInfoById(this.subId).pipe(
    map(res => res),
    catchError(e => throwError(e)) //of(this.errorMessageService.getErrorMessage(e))
  )
)
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
      //this.groupInfo = res[0];
      //this.subProjectInfo = res[1];
    },
    error => {
      console.log(this.errorMessageService.getErrorMessage(error));
    }
  );
```

Issue:

both `this.groupInfo = res[0];` and `this.subProjectInfo = res[1];` are resulting in

```
(TS) type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Group[]'.
Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'.
```

and

```
(TS) type '{}' is not assignable to type 'SubProject'.
Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'.
```

In subscribe `res is [{},{}]`

console log

[image]

How to proceed here?

**update 1:**

This worked, no more errors

```
this.groupInfo = <Group[]>res[0];
this.subProjectInfo = <SubProject>res[1];
```

Do i have the proper solution in place? forkJoin is inside the component.

Comment: You dont need to add the map, since its not doing anything.its a dead code. plus, I would take out the if inside the forkJoin and init it outside and use the variable inside, it will be much more clear to read. Last thing, since you are using forkJoin, your response in the subscribe contains multiple values, so for readability, I would choose to set it as ([arr, obj]) so you can access each one directly instead of the use of [0],[1]

Comment: I am fairly new to angular and rxjs in particular. This piece of code took me some time to write. Can you give me an example code to remove map and provide ([arr, obj])?

Comment: Also, if one call fails, i don't want the other call to go through.